# How to use pthread_mutex and it's functions within a class?

Tags: c++, class, locking, pthreads, mutex

I have searched for many hours for a solution, but cannot find an easy answer.
I got a class, which uses pthreads. The actual function pointer is static within the class, and I need to lock on a mutex, because so far I get "weird" results (parameters not being passed correctly).

However the pthread_mutex_lock and unlock will not work within the function given to the thread, because it is in a static member function, yet I cannot have the function non static because it won't work inside the class, and I cannot move it outside the class, because it won't be able to access required info.

The following code should explain:

```
class Fight{

     pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex;
     static void *thread_run_fighter(void *temp);

  public:

    Fight();
    bool thread_round(Individual &a, int a_u, Individual &b, int b_u);
    std::vector<Individual> tournament();
  };
```

And the cpp file:

```
    Fight::Fight(){
       thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    }

    bool Fight::thread_round(Individual &a, int a_u, Individual &b, int b_u){

    if (a.saved and b.saved){
       a.uniform = a_u;
       b.uniform = b_u;
       Individual *one = &a;
       Individual *two = &b;      
       pthread_t a_thread, b_thread;
       int a_thread_id, b_thread_id;
       a_thread_id = pthread_create(&a_thread,NULL,Fight::thread_run_fighter,(void*) one);
       b_thread_id = pthread_create(&b_thread,NULL,Fight::thread_run_fighter,(void*) two);

       pthread_join( a_thread, NULL);
       pthread_join( b_thread, NULL); 
       return true;
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
   }

   void *Fight::thread_run_fighter(void *temp){

     Individual *indiv;
     indiv = (class Individual*)temp;
     pthread_mutex_lock( &thread_mutex );
     indiv->execute(indiv->uniform);
     pthread_mutex_unlock( &thread_mutex );

   }
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could shed some light into this. I have been stuck for some hours now, and I could not find any info whatsoever.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By 'doesn't work' I assume you mean it won't compile since you're trying to use an instance member in a `static` member function.

But the bigger question is why are you trying to use threads for this?

The thread function you have is entirely protected by the mutex anyway - you'll get the same (or better) performance by simply calling

```
a.execute(a.uniform);
b.execute(b.uniform);
```

instead of spinning up the threads then waiting for them to complete.

---

But if you really want to use threads (maybe you're learning about them) and you want your static member function to be able to deal with instance members, here are some pointers. To get that to work, you'll need to somehow pass an instance of the Fight object to the `static` thread function:

```
// somewhere in `class Fight` definition:
//
// a structure that will let you pass a Fight* instance pointer
//  along with an Individual* to work on in the the
//  thread function

struct context {
    Fight* me;
    Individual* indiv;
};



// ...

// in Fight::thread_round():
//  package up data to pass to the thread function
context one = {this, &a };  // instead of Individual *one = &a;
context two = {this, &b };  // instead of Individual *two = &b;
```

Finally, `Fight::thread_run_fighter()`:

```
void *Fight::thread_run_fighter(void *temp)
{
    // pull out the Fight object instance and the Individual
    //  object to work on
    context* ctx = (context*) temp;
    Individual *indiv = ctx->indiv;
    Fight* me = ctx->me;

    // do the work (in a pretty serialized fashion, unfortunately)
    pthread_mutex_lock( &me->thread_mutex );
    indiv->execute(indiv->uniform);
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &me->thread_mutex );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By "problems" I mean I get unpredictable errors such as individuals with changed parameters. I haven't mentioned it in the post, but I need to thread because the actual execution forks and execs, and then waits. But I think you found the problem, it doesn't have to do with mutexes, it's because I've set it static it keeps executing the first individual passed as param, and only works when the object is recreated and function recalled!
I will try your suggestion and see if I can get it to work! Thank you!

Comment: @Alex: I guess I'm not sure how you'd get to the point of runtime problems since I can't understand how the `thread_run_fighter()` presented in the question would even compile. Since it's a static member function trying to use non-static members, it should cause a compile time error.  But if you're unblocked somehow, that's good news.

Comment: Well I tried what you suggested, But I still get "weird" problems. Parameters are not passed correctly, Individuals claim not having been saved, etc. I think I'm going at this the wrong way. Thank you however for showing to me my error and how to use the mutex lock and unlock!
PS: No I didn't get any compile errors!

Answer (score 2):

The first question which I'd like to ask: do you need portable code? If yes, never pass C++ function to pthread_create. The reason: interface for pthread_create requires function declared as extern "C", and you are lucky (thanks to x86:) ) that static member method suits for this, but there is no guarantee that the same will be on other platform or compilers.

The second, you have called `thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` after mutex creation, as far as I remember standard say that this is allowed on initialization only.

And finally, `pthread_mutex_lock( &thread_mutex )` withing static method will not allowed because static method does not have access to object's non-static members, so you need to pass a pointer to you object. You may declare `pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex;` and `void *thread_run_fighter(void *temp);` as global, as I see it will be the simplest way in this case.

And some notes: what about boost::threads? I think it will be better to use it instead of creating your own solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think all you missed was to use `&indiv->thread_mutex` instead of omitting the `indiv->` object.

EDIT: Do note that it's probably better to use a static cast rather than the C-style "shotgun" cast: `Individual *indiv = static_cast<Individual*>(temp);`

Answer (score 0):

inside of the static `thread_run_fighter` you are using the non static `thread_mutex`. thread_mutex must be created with pthread_mutex_init prior to it's use.

Comment: Actually `thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` is a substitute for the `pthread_mutex_init` call when all you need is straight defaults.

Comment: yes, but it still is not static. and the ctor may be run or may be not run before thread_run_fighter is called... I think the code does not compile...

Comment: ah, sorry, no coffe so far... why do you create threads? the way it is now both fightes lock on the same mutex, so indiv->execute for a is run and the indiv->execute for b is run since the mutex is the same. you could have called the two functions in the thread_round also - since it is waiting for them anyway. what do you actually want to achieve with using the mutices?

Comment: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` can *only* be used as an initializer for statically allocated mutexes (that is, global variables, `static` class members, or `static` function members).  It *cannot* be used as a dynamic initializer, like in this case, and doing so is undefined behavior.  You need to initialize it with `pthread_mutex_init` in this case.

Comment: I've changed the constructor to use pthread_mutex_init, didn't know there was a difference.
I might have been going at this the wrong way. I should probably implement the mutex within the individual class or the vector that holds the individuals rather than the fight class.
I create threads in order to parallelize the execution, it's a genetic programming optimization app. Each individual->execute() forks and starts another binary which connects to a simulation server while the app waits for it to finish. I want to run 4 or 8 threads instead of only one in order to speed up calculations.